# Dynamically Show/Hide Radio buttons of a Radio button group using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking for a way to Show/ Hide some of the Radio buttons of a Radio button group using JavaScript.

How can this be achieved?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *id* attribute identifies the individual radio buttons. All of them will be related to the group by the *name* attribute

You can get the individual radio buttons using something like

```
var rbtn = document.getElementById('radioButton1');
```

Then set the display or visibility style to hide or show.

```
rbtn.style.display = 'none'; // 'block' or 'inline' if you want to show.
```

Comment: better to set the display property because visibility hide still takes space.

Comment: I tried this. It just hides the control but not the text following the radio button. How should I hide that text?

Comment: @Loginissue: You can hide the text in the same way by wrapping it in a <span> or <div> and giving the wrapper element an id.

Comment: Isn't each text entry tied up to the control?

Comment: Actually no.. I'd create radio buttons like - 

<input id="radioButton1" type="radio">ChoiceText

....so, the text is separate. As weenaak said, put them in a span or a div and hide/show them too...

<input id="radioButton1" type="radio" /><span id="radioText1">Choice</span>

Comment: Also, what I've said is pure HTML/JavaScript. UI Frameworks let you do all this in a single function call.

Answer (score 3):

```
document.getElementById('myRadioButtonId').style.display = 'none'; //hide it

document.getElementById('myRadioButtonId').style.display = 'block'; //show it
```

Comment: This seems to hide the control but not the text following the control. How do I hide the text also?

Comment: Do exactly the same thing for that, e.g. document.getElementById('myTextElementId').style.display = 'none';

Answer (score 0):

That's a very generic question, so I can only offer a very generic answer.  Using jQuery, for example:

```
$("#some-selector .of-some-kind .for-the-things-you-wish-to-hide").hide();
```

Of course, what you're selecting, and under what circumstances you want to hide it can dramatically impact the best way to go about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Apply a CSS class to the radiobuttons then use a loop to set the `display = 'none'` for each radiobutton.

Firstly, we need a cross-browser getElementsByClassName function

```
/*
    Developed by Robert Nyman, http://www.robertnyman.com
    Code/licensing: http://code.google.com/p/getelementsbyclassname/
*/
var getElementsByClassName = function (className, tag, elm){
    if (document.getElementsByClassName) {
        getElementsByClassName = function (className, tag, elm) {
            elm = elm || document;
            var elements = elm.getElementsByClassName(className),
                nodeName = (tag)? new RegExp("\\b" + tag + "\\b", "i") : null,
                returnElements = [],
                current;
            for(var i=0, il=elements.length; i<il; i+=1){
                current = elements[i];
                if(!nodeName || nodeName.test(current.nodeName)) {
                    returnElements.push(current);
                }
            }
            return returnElements;
        };
    }
    else if (document.evaluate) {
        getElementsByClassName = function (className, tag, elm) {
            tag = tag || "*";
            elm = elm || document;
            var classes = className.split(" "),
                classesToCheck = "",
                xhtmlNamespace = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml",
                namespaceResolver = (document.documentElement.namespaceURI === xhtmlNamespace)? xhtmlNamespace : null,
                returnElements = [],
                elements,
                node;
            for(var j=0, jl=classes.length; j<jl; j+=1){
                classesToCheck += "[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' " + classes[j] + " ')]";
            }
            try {
                elements = document.evaluate(".//" + tag + classesToCheck, elm, namespaceResolver, 0, null);
            }
            catch (e) {
                elements = document.evaluate(".//" + tag + classesToCheck, elm, null, 0, null);
            }
            while ((node = elements.iterateNext())) {
                returnElements.push(node);
            }
            return returnElements;
        };
    }
    else {
        getElementsByClassName = function (className, tag, elm) {
            tag = tag || "*";
            elm = elm || document;
            var classes = className.split(" "),
                classesToCheck = [],
                elements = (tag === "*" && elm.all)? elm.all : elm.getElementsByTagName(tag),
                current,
                returnElements = [],
                match;
            for(var k=0, kl=classes.length; k<kl; k+=1){
                classesToCheck.push(new RegExp("(^|\\s)" + classes[k] + "(\\s|$)"));
            }
            for(var l=0, ll=elements.length; l<ll; l+=1){
                current = elements[l];
                match = false;
                for(var m=0, ml=classesToCheck.length; m<ml; m+=1){
                    match = classesToCheck[m].test(current.className);
                    if (!match) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (match) {
                    returnElements.push(current);
                }
            }
            return returnElements;
        };
    }
    return getElementsByClassName(className, tag, elm);
};
```

then use like so

```
var radioButtons = getElementsByClassName('myClassName', 'input');
var len = radioButtons.length;

for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
    radioButtons[i].style.display = 'none';
```

Answer (score 0):

Everybody else has nailed it, so I'll put in a plug for the frameworks.

Using jquery or mootools or another framework makes this super easy:

MooTools:

```
$$('input[name=myRadioName]).setStyle('display','none');
```

or

```
$$('input[name=myRadioName]).fade('out');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
<span id="myspan"><input id="radioButton1" type="radio" />Some label goes here</span>
```

Then

```
document.getElementById('myspan').style.display="none"; //inline or block to display again
```

If you are using JQuery then

```
$('myspan').hide(); // show() to display again
```